# Generate array of complex numbers with absolute value one in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

In Julia, I would like to randomly generate an array of arbitrary size, where all the elements of the array are complex numbers with absolute value one. Is there perhaps any way to do this within Julia?

Comment: `exp.((2*im*π).*rand(10))` should work (replace `10` with number of values or use `rand(10,10)` for matrix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got four options so far:

```
f1(n) = exp.((2*im*π).*rand(n))

f2(n) = map(x->(z = x[1]+im*x[2] ; z ./ abs(z) ),
  eachcol(randn(2,n)))

f3(n) = [im*x[1]+x[2] for x in sincos.(2π*rand(n))]

f4(n) = cispi.(2 .*rand(n))
```

We have:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> begin
         @btime f1(1_000);
         @btime f2(1_000);
         @btime f3(1_000);
         @btime f4(1_000);
       end;
  29.390 μs (2 allocations: 23.69 KiB)
  15.559 μs (2 allocations: 31.50 KiB)
  25.733 μs (4 allocations: 47.38 KiB)
  27.662 μs (2 allocations: 23.69 KiB)
```

Not a crucial difference.

Comment: what about `cispi(2.*rand(n))`?

Comment: @OscarSmith Also an option. Didn't know about `cispi`. Adding to answer

Answer (score 2):

One way is:

```
randcomplex() = (c = Complex(rand(2)...); c / abs(c))

randcomplex(numwanted) = [randcomplex() for _ in 1:numwanted]
```

or

```
randcomplex(dims...) = (a = zeros(Complex, dims...); for i in eachindex(a) a[i] = randcomplex() end; a)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something faster, here are two options. They return a perhaps slightly unfamiliar type, but it is equivalent to a regular Vector

```
function f5(n)
    r = rand(2, n)
    for i in 1:n
        a = sqrt(r[1, i]^2 + r[2, i]^2)
        r[1, i] /= a
        r[2, i] /= a
    end
    return reinterpret(reshape, ComplexF64, r)
end

using LoopVectorization: @turbo
function f5t(n)
    r = rand(2, n)
    @turbo for i in 1:n
        a = sqrt(r[1, i]^2 + r[2, i]^2)
        r[1, i] /= a
        r[2, i] /= a
    end
    return reinterpret(reshape, ComplexF64, r)
end

julia> @btime f5(1000);
  4.186 μs (1 allocation: 15.75 KiB)

julia> @btime f5t(1000);
  2.900 μs (1 allocation: 15.75 KiB)
```

Comment: Note that these produce results in the first quadrant, `using Plots; f5(100) |> scatter`. You could use `randn` (at the cost of some speed) or something like `x = r[1,i] - 0.5` before `a`.

Comment: You're right. That's a blunder...

Comment: @mcabbott Using `x = r[1,i] - 0.5` wouldn't do as `using Plots; historgram(angle.(f5(10000)))` will reveal. Using `randn` is crucial for Gaussian projection of 2D Gaussian circularly symmetric distribution.

Comment: Oh right, of course. Similarly `rand` isn't angle-uniform in the 1st quadrant, has a peak near 45°. I guess not entirely clear what the original question required.